# plot.ly Hover Box Size attribute

Tags: python, hover, plotly

I'm using the [plot.ly Python api](https://plot.ly/python/reference/) and cannot figure out how to adjust the size of the plotly hover box size.

For example, in the visualization below the label for *CollegeClass....* is truncated. I would like to adjust the length of the string in the hover box.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably found an answer since but :

By setting 'text' and passing it to your hoverinfo.
In your example if you set text='CollegeClass' and set your hoverinfo = 'text' you will get the result you expect.
It seems that the name of the trace get truncated while the text or label that you pass isn't.

```
data = [
go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2],
    y=[1, 3, 2],
    mode='markers',
    text=['Text A', 'Text B', 'Text C']
    hoverinfo = 'text'
)]
```

Copied from **https://plot.ly/python/text-and-annotations/#adding-hover-text-to-data-in-line-and-scatter-plots**
Not that in my case I had to set hoverinfo = 'text' while in the example it seems to work without.

Answer (score 7):

I might be a little late but I found a batter solution
Adding `hoverlabel: {namelength :-1}` into my trace object did the trick.

From [Here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/460#issuecomment-457214572)

Comment: Note: In python with a bar graph I had to add this to my `update_layout` call and the format for the above in that instance is `hoverlabel_namelength=-1`